# cant update or install anything tor geoipd not installed

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, dpkg

when i go to the Ubuntu Software Center i get and try to update i get the error

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 172818 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tor (0.2.4.20-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in package tor-browser 3.5.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tor-geoipdb:
 tor-geoipdb depends on tor (>= 0.2.4.20-1); however:
  Package tor is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package tor-geoipdb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

how do i fix this? and what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Execute these commands in your Terminal:

> sudo dpkg -r tor-browser tor-geoipdb
>   sudo apt-get install -f

Run these commands to install TOR:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install tor-browser

Comment: My pleasure! Please consider marking the helpful answers correct as well. :)

Comment: Err... Don't add random UNOFFICIAL repos from the internet and install them. Especially not privacy software. Check this official link for installing Tor https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en